# Website indexed with a question mark

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect the subfolder /?/ to my main url. This website runs with Wordpress.

I don't understand why, but since last night the URL of my site on Google ends with **/?/** ( **http: //www.example.com/?/** INSTEAD of **http://www.example.com/** )

I try to make a 301 in my htaccess :

```
 redirect 301 /?/ http://www.example.com
```

But it's not working ???

If you have any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `mod_rewrite` rule for this like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?/
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

Make sure this is your **very first rule** in root .htaccess.